# Using Java labels correctly

Tags: java

I'm trying to properly use the alternative for the go to statement in JAVA. I'm not sure if "labels" are the appropriate alternative for the go to statement.

I'm attempting to do the following in my Tic tac toe controller..

```
try {
      out.append(m + "\n");
      while (true) {
        out.append("Enter a move for " + m.getTurn().toString() + ":\n");
        label:
        {
          String element1 = scan.next();
          if (quitGameHelper(element1, m)) {
            return;
          }
          String regex = "[-+]?\\d+";
          boolean showInFirstAttempt = false;
          while (!Pattern.matches(regex, element1)) {
            if (quitGameHelper(element1, m)) {
              return;
            }
            if (!Pattern.matches(regex, element1)) {
              out.append("Not a valid number: " + element1 + "\n");
              goto label;
            }
            element1 = scan.next();
          }

          String element2 = scan.next();
          if (quitGameHelper(element2, m)) {
            return;
          }
          while (!Pattern.matches(regex, element2)) {
            if (quitGameHelper(element2, m)) {
              return;
            }
            if (!Pattern.matches(regex, element2)) {
              out.append("Not a valid number: " + element2 + "\n");
              goto label;
            }
            element2 = scan.next();
          }

          element1Int = Integer.parseInt(element1) - 1;
          element2Int = Integer.parseInt(element2) - 1;
          try {
            m.move(element1Int, element2Int);
            out.append(m + "\n");
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            out.append("Not a valid move: " + (element1Int + 1) + ", " + (element2Int + 1) + "\n");
          }

          final boolean gameOver = m.isGameOver();
          if (gameOver) {
            final Player winner = m.getWinner();
            if (winner == null) {
              out.append("Game is over! Tie game.");
            } else {
              out.append("Game is over! " + winner + " wins.");
            }
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I realize `goto label` is not recognised in JAVA. But, I want to incorporate that behaviour.

Would really appreciate any pointers on this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can only use `break label` or `continue label`.

Comment: I tried using break, but it doesn' work. Using ```continue``` shows an error. (```Not a loop label: 'label'```)

Comment: Hint: You don't have to write your entire program in a single method. Then, you can use return (or throw) rather than labels.

Answer (score 1):

Put the label on a looping construct:

```
outerWhileLabel:
while (true) {
    out.append("Enter a move for " + m.getTurn().toString() + ":\n");
    // other code
    while {
        // other code 
        continue outerWhileLabel;
    }
    // other code
}
```

Give your label a better, more meaningful name than “label”.